# Cannot log into phpmyadmin but can connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, passwords

Today I met a strange problem. With mysql username"root" and password "lab" I was able to connect to the database. However, with the same account info I failed to log into phpmyadmin! I can see the log page, when inputting password, just refresh again and again. Any idea about it?

Your replies are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in phpMyAdmin to disallow the root-user for security-reasons. Check if it is set in your config.inc.php.

Documentation: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#AllowRoot

Comment: Unfortunately it is not for this reason .